# Log time taken for sync JMS call

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In a spring integration project I have a outbound gateway to send and receive messages synchronously. I would like to log the time taken for such an operation.

```
<jms:outbound-gateway id="jmsOutGateway"
                   request-destination="outQueue"
                   request-channel="outboundJmsRequests"
                   reply-channel="jmsReplies"/>
```

I tried searching but could only find examples of using AOP and PerformanceMonitorInterceptor to trace methods.

Comment: Is **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098254/distributed-jms-based-logging-falling-flat)** related?  "Doing any logging in db/jms/socket/etc synchronously is asking for problems and a lot of them."

Comment: Well not exactly. I am not going to add any logging to the service. I am merely trying to log the time taken for a test client between sending a request and receiving a reply. The test client is written using Spring Integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="jmsOutGateway"
                   request-destination="outQueue"
                   request-channel="outboundJmsRequests"
                   reply-channel="jmsReplies">
    <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor"/>
    </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

The `<request-handler-advice-chain>` is applied for the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage` method and `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>` populates `JmsOutboundGateway` - an implementation of `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`.